# passing multiple form data to a jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Really all I need is some help with how to pass multiple variables from a form to jQuery.

The details:

I am trying to create a font color-mixer for my page. I successfully created a greyscale version of it that as people type in the parameters it makes the font brighter or darker. I have the same for the background. The code is this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#leftsettingswindow").on("keyup", "#fontbrightness2", function(){
    var savedThis = this;
    setTimeout(function () {
      var ftbrVal = savedThis.value; 
        $('#content').css("color", "rgb(" + ftbrVal + "," + ftbrVal + "," + ftbrVal + ")");
        }, 1200);
    });});
```

the HTML is this

```
    <div id="fontbrightness">Font brightness B&W: 
      <input type="text" size="4"  value="0" id="fontbrightness2">%       </div>
```

The question is this (Of course I would not be asking if I was not a novice in jQuery)
How do I pass multiple parameters so that I can have a font color mixer?

the HTML is this:

```
<div id="fontcolor">
Font Color Mixer
 <div id="fontred">
 Red <input type="text" class="fcolors" size="4"  value="100" n="fr">%
 </div>
 <div id="fontgreen">
 Green <input type="text" class="fcolors" size="4"  value="100" n="fg">%
 </div>
 <div id="fontblue">
 Blue <input type="text" class="fcolors" size="4"  value="100" n="fb">%
 </div>

</div>
```

as you can see from the different tags in the HTML code I was experimenting, but did not achieve the desired effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You basically need to capture all three values individually and concatenate them into one. I would also suggest using a slider control so that you can set specified range of numbers that can be applied (e.g. rgb goes from 0 to 255). If you use text fields, you will also need to check and see if the value is above 255.

Using input type number: http://jsfiddle.net/aSsqe/1/

Using input type range: http://jsfiddle.net/aSsqe/2/

```
$(function() {
    function getInputValues(){
        var r = $('#red').val(),
            g = $('#green').val(),
            b = $('#blue').val(),
            rgb = 'rgb(' + r + ',' + g + ',' + b + ')';

        $('#result').css('background', rgb);      
    };
    getInputValues();

    $('#input-container').on('change', 'input', function(){
        getInputValues();
    });
});
```